# ViewModelLocator for MEF

Tags: c#, wpf, mef, viewmodellocator

I would like to know if there is `ViewModelLocator` for MEF. If there is, could you please give me links to it? I plan to use it together with prism.

Comment: Seriously: Have you actually tried typing "ViewModelLocator for MEF" into Google?

Answer (score 0):

I use [MEFedMVVM](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2010/04/24/an-introduction-to-mefedmvvm-part-1/) as part of [Cinch](http://cinch.codeplex.com/), but you could use it standalone or with Prism.